# Elimination returning true instead of correct answer

Tags: equation-solving

I define the following functions:

```
left[x_] := -c Exp[alpha x]

box[x_] := a Sin[k x] + b Cos[k x]

right[x_] := c Exp[-alpha x]

dleft[x_] = D[left[x], x]

dbox[x_] = D[box[x], x]

dright[x_] = D[right[x], x]
```

Next I have a system of 4 equations:

```
Eliminate[{

left[-l] == box[-l] && 

dbox[l] == dright[l] && 


   right[l] == box[l] && 

dleft[-l] == dbox[-l]
  }, {a, b, c}, InverseFunctions -> True]
```

I expect to get `k cot[k l] = -alpha`. Instead I get `"True"` as the answer.

IF I use the command (drop c from elimination list):

```
Eliminate[{left[-l] == box[-l] && dbox[l] == dright[l] && 
   right[l] == box[l] && dleft[-l] == dbox[-l]
  }, {a, b}, InverseFunctions -> True]
```

I get: `alpha c Sin[k l] == -c k Cos[k l]` which is the correct answer if you cancel `c` from both sides.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Eliminate` uses the given set of equations to eliminate the requested variables from those equations, returning the equations not needed to do the eliminations.  Thus,

```
Eliminate[{left[-l] == box[-l] && dbox[l] == dright[l] && right[l] == box[l] && 
    dleft[-l] == dbox[-l]}, {a, b}, InverseFunctions -> True]
```

eliminates variable `a` and `b`, returning the remaining equation.

```
(* alpha c Sin[k l] == -c k Cos[k l] *)
```

To `Eliminate` the remaining variable, `c` requires the use of the remaining equation

```
Eliminate[%, {c}]
```

leaves no equations, and `Eliminate` returns

```
(* True *)
```

(Why it does not return `Null`, instead, I do not know.)

This behavior is illustrated perhaps more clearly in the simple example,

```
Eliminate[e == 1 && d == 1, e]
(* d == 1 *)
Eliminate[%, d]
(* True *)
```